# VB.Net Issue reading text to a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple sticky notes application that I've been working on for a while now, and I've ran into a problem importing/loading in text to a textbox. Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub newNote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles newNote.Click
    Dim newNoteFrm As New Notes
    newNoteFrm.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub exportNote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exportNote.Click
    Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim myStream As Stream
    saveFile.Title = "Export/Save Note"
    saveFile.Filter = ".txt|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
    saveFile.FilterIndex = 0

    If saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        RichTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        Me.Text = saveFile.FileName.ToString
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub importNote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles importNote.Click
    Dim openFIle As New OpenFileDialog
    openFIle.Filter = ".txt|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
    openFIle.FilterIndex = 0
    If openFIle.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(openFIle.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue comes at this part:

```
    Private Sub importNote_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles importNote.Click
    Dim openFIle As New OpenFileDialog
    openFIle.Filter = ".txt|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
    openFIle.FilterIndex = 0
    If openFIle.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(openFIle.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

For some reason, when I export any file from this application as a .txt, I can't re-open it in the application without issue. This is what is happening when I re-open a file that I saved from this program specifically. (Note: If I save a .txt file from notepad, or wordpad, I can open it with no issue. It only occurs when I save it from my application and open it in my application.):
This is what happens when I re-open a file:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Kristen ITC;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs18 (my text that I saved shows here)\par
}
```

^ This is placed into the rich text box, and I'm unsure why. I'm assuming I'm saving files incorrectly? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how do you save your file?

```
 RichTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
```

This save the file in RTF format, the name, (and the extension choosen), of the file has no effect to the format because you have used the `RichTextboxStreamType.RichText` option.

You should use the RichTextBox method that is able to understand the RTF text saved by the SaveFile method.

```
If openFIle.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    RichTextBox1.LoadFile(openFIle.FileName)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if I was saving it in a weird format or what, but this worked. I only used the other method because I read it was the best way, but I guess not. Anyway, thanks for that!

Comment: I'm aware of it, I just had to wait a few minutes before it let me accept.